# How can I configure Hibernate with environment variable

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, configuration, heroku

So i want to deploy my java app on heroku. Once deployed it sets an environment variable DATABASE_URL. I want to use that as my url for hibernate. I currently have hibernate.cfg.xml and there i set the url jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/db like this . How can i change it to take DATABASE_URL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the ways is to use [setProperty(String propertyName, String value)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) of [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) to explicitly override the value of `hibernate.connection.url` before creating the SessionFactory.

To get the environment variables , you can use [System.getenv(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) .

```
/**Load the hibernate.cfg.xml from the classpath**/
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thank you so much figured it out though a few minutes ago. :)

Comment: Please let me know if it is okay or not. Good luck :)

Comment: You may need to tweak the string returned from System.getenv("DATABASE_URL").

Answer (score 20):

I searched a lot for another solution without programming anything in java itself.
I came to the following conclusion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.check_nullability">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate_username}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate_password}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://${hibernate_db_host}/${hibernate_db_name}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate_show_sql}</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And I start my application with following vmargs:

```
-Dhibernate_username=test -Dhibernate_password=testpassword -Dhibernate_db_host=localhost -Dhibernate_db_name=test -Dhibernate_show_sql=true
```

I post this solution to this old Post, because I found this in an old forum post (Google Search Side 3+ ^^). And I think this is very useful.

Comment: Why do we need to pass them in as VM  arguments and not just set them in environment variables?

Comment: In our usecase the hibernate config file is packed in a jar-file. It is a bit tedious for our clients to edit these files. Thats the reason we packed them in the VM arguments, those are easier to configure.

Comment: Thanks for the response on an old topic! Is there any way that might be able to set it up like you have but instead of VMargs use environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

May this help you,

I am using HSQL DB of Jboss AS 5.x and hibernate to dynamically create tables and using following *.cfg.xml file.

which is using `$`JBOSS_HOME as environment variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <session-factory>

            <!-- Database connection settings -->

            <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:$JBOSS_HOME/server/test/data/hypersonic/localDB</property>
            <property name="connection.username">sa</property>

            <property name="connection.password"></property>

            <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

            <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->

            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <!--  Mapping files  -->
            <mapping resource="friends_presence_log.hbm.xml" />
            <mapping resource="profileuuid.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
```

So, Its mean if you want to use environment variable into Jboss config then your can use normally which later taken by internal hibernate.jar utility  and you get connection or things normally as in a java program.

Comment: Using $VAR does not get parsed

Answer (score 1):

If you use a build tool like gradle, you can use placeholders enclosed by @...@ as follows:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
      <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
         @db_dialect@
      </property>

      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
         @db_driver@
      </property>

      <!-- Assume test is the database name -->

      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
         @db_url@
      </property>

      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
         @db_user@
      </property>

      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
         @db_password@
      </property>

      <!-- Cannot use anything other than "validate" in production. --> 
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

      <!-- Connection pooling -->
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">500</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1024</property>

      <!-- Your mappings -->
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then in *build.gradle* you'd have something like this:

```
def db_driver = System.getenv('MYAPP_DB_DRIVER')
def db_url = System.getenv('MYAPP_DB_URL')
def db_dialect = System.getenv('MYAPP_DB_DIALECT')

processResources {
    filesMatching(['**/*.xml', '**/*.properties', '**/*.json']) {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            'db_driver': db_driver,
            'db_url': db_url,
            'db_dialect': db_dialect,
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step answer:

1. All hibernate configuration properties can be overidden with a Java system property -Dhibernate_property=value - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic
2. If you don't have easy access to your java command line with a script, then use the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable to insert the hibernate configuration properties - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

For example here's an environment variable I set up in my docker-compose file to turn on or off hibernate's SQL logging behavior at runtime

```
  mybackend:
    image: dkr.myrepo.com/my-backend
    environment:
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dhibernate.show_sql=true -Dhibernate.format_sql=true
```